# swift button hide/show not working

Tags: swift

I have the view.
When I click on the btnStartWork, I want to the button is set to hidden (worked) and the label startTime show the start time(worked) and the btnEndWork is showing (worked).
When I clicked on the btnEndWork I no button is hidden and btnEndWork is still showing. Also he set to the endTime Label the end time but update the startTime too. That is really wired.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var startTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnStartWorkLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnEndWorkLabel: UIButton!

@IBAction func btnStartWork(_ sender: Any) {
    let currentdate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentdate)

    startTime.text = "\(convertedDate)"

    btnStartWorkLabel.isHidden = true
    btnEndWorkLabel.isHidden = false
}
@IBAction func btnEndWork(_ sender: Any) {
    let currentdate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentdate)

    endTime.text = "\(convertedDate)"

    btnStartWorkLabel.isHidden = false
    btnEndWorkLabel.isHidden = true
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

**Update Question**

How could I save the times, to work with both times, when the btnEndWork is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is wired wrong, look at the controller in interface builder for multiple connections (if you copy and paste a label or button the connection is copied too) and try adding:

```
print("Start button pressed")
```

to

```
@IBAction func btnStartWork(_ sender: Any)
```

and

```
print("End button pressed")
```

to

```
@IBAction func btnEndWork(_ sender: Any)
```

to see if the output is correct when you press the buttons.

Comment: I copy paste alot so run into this all the time, also be aware if you copy paste from another controller it will hold connection to previous controller.